# Why doesn't "break" stop this for loop?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, break

```
for i in range(999*999):
    if ispalindrome(999*999-i)==True and isprime(999*999-i) == False:
        factors = listfactors(999*999-i)
        for j in range(len(factors)):
            if len(str(factors[j])) == 3 and len(str(int((999*999-i)/factors[j])))==3:
                print(999*999-i)
                quit()
```

This is my code. I want to check whether these conditions are true and then stop once I've found the first one, but it prints all of the numbers that fit the conditions in the console. My thinking was that it should stop when it's got the first number

EDIT: I tried using quit() instead of break, but this still doesn't work, which I don't understand. I did try it with two break statements, but that didn't work. I wonder whether I got the indentation wrong.

Comment: so... where is the `break`?

Comment: I'm assuming you are using `quit()` because `break` wasn't working. You have 2 levels of `for` loop `break` will only break out of one level. Probably easier to put this into a function and `return`

Comment: whoops, thats a later version of the code where I tried using quit() instead. I wasn't sure whether I'd need to have two breaks because and I've got two loops. The quit() should do the same thing though, and only give me the one number though, right?

Comment: @Emily No, using two breaks would not solve the problem, except when using in addition to a variable that tells you whether there is a match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to quit a double loop, use a function instead and return from the function. A break only works for the innermost loop.

Exampe:

```
def whatever():
    for i in range(999 * 999):
        if ispalindrome(999 * 999 - i) and not isprime(999 * 999 - i):
            factors = listfactors(999 * 999 - i)
            for j in factors:
                if len(str(j)) == 3 and len(str(int((999 * 999 - i) / j))) == 3:
                    return 999*999-i

print(whatever())
```

Answer (score 1):

the function `break` will only go out of 1 level. An easier way to do what you want is to make it a function as stated by Hubert. If you really do not want to use a function, you could create another variable `continue` and set it to True and check if it is not True at every level and if so break, then set it to False once it finds the answer, this way when it is found it will exit each loop as continue is no longer True.

Hope it helps.

P.S. You should mark a tick by Hubert's answer since it is solving your problem.